# Solve an Equation with Ceiling Function

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Given the following Term

$$n=\left\lceil{\frac{a}{b}}\right\rceil \quad \text{with} \quad a,b\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$$

Is there a way to get $b$ if $a$ and $n$ are given? I. e. what is the solution for:
$$b=?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$b=a/n$ is clearly a solution. Is it the only one? study what happens if $b<a/n$ and $b>a/n$.

Comment: I've found this nice equivalence on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Equivalences): $\lceil x \rceil = n \iff n -1 < x \le n$. So I have $n-1\lt \frac{a}{b} \le n$. I can apply the multiplicative inverse, because it is strongly monotonic for positive numbers and $n-1,\frac{a}{b},n\ge 0$: $\frac{1}{n-1}>\frac{b}{a}\ge\frac{1}{n}$. Finally I get $\frac{a}{n-1}>b\ge\frac{a}{n}$. So is the solution for $b=\left(\frac{a}{n-1},\frac{a}{n}\right\}$?

Comment: It should be $b\in[\frac{a}{n},\frac{a}{n-1})$.